# Python C-extenstions cannot be loaded

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to embed some python into my visual studio c++ code. The c++ code is:

```
#include    <Python.h>

int main ()
{
    char filename[] = "hello_world.py";
    FILE* fp;

    PyObject* pInt;
    Py_Initialize();

    fp = _Py_fopen(filename, "r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, filename);

    Py_Finalize();


    return 0;
}
```

and the associated python script is:

```
import importlib
np = importlib.import_module('numpy')
plt = importlib.import_module('matplotlib.pyplot')

print("hello world")

plt.figure()
plt.plot(1,1)
plt.show(block=True)
```

when I actually run the code I get the following error:

> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
> many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed.
>
> We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
>
> ```
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
> ```
>
> Please note and check the following:
>
> - The Python version is: Python3.8 from "D:\4D
>   Avsys\Code\Temp\Temp\Debug\Temp.exe"
> - The NumPy version is:
>   "1.19.1"
>
> and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully
> study the documentation linked above for further help.
>
> Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

I've read through the url that is provided in the error output and could find nothing to solve the problem. After reading several other posts regarding the same issue I have done the following:

1. Uninstalled all versions of python on the computer.
2. Reinstalled Python Version 3.8 for windows. (allowed installer to add path variable and downloaded debug symbols and libraries).
3. Installed matplotlib via pip install
4. Uninstalled and reinstalled setuptools and numpy via pip
5. Ran the python code successfully in both cmd and powershell (VS developer and general environments)

I can run simple python code through c++, so I'm pretty sure that part is okay.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT [Found Solution]:

After reading through https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15919
if you put visual studio into release mode then there are no more issues with importing numpy. Be sure to update the properties of the project again to include the python \include and \libs directories in the project.

Comment: Based on searching for this error online, it has to do with folders where certain libs got installed.  Solution usually involves finding them and appending to the PATH.  For example maybe a location that contains site-packages\numpy\.libs

Comment: @Abel thank you for the response, I have tried adding 'site-packages\numpy\.libs' ; 'site-packages\numpy\lib' ; 'site-packages\numpy\core\include' ; 'site-packages\numpy\core\lib' and basically any other possible lib to the PATH with no luck. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15919 if you put visual studio into release mode then there are no more issues with importing numpy. Be sure to update the properties of the project again to include the python \include and \libs directories in the project.